# AVR and MOSFET gate resistor

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, avr, driver

I am driving a MOSFET with AVR using PWM for controlling a motor. I have a 4K7 pull-up resistor on the gate. My question is, do I need a resistor in between the AVR pin and the gate? (The mosfet is [NX2301P](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NX2301P.pdf))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you do not need a series resistor. If you put one in there it would limit the current a bit and might help in case of some layout issue, but it's not necessary.

Why the rather low gate pull down and why a pull down rather than pullup? Normally I'd expect to see more like a 20K pullup so if the AVR output is high impedance the motor turns **off**. A pull down resistor on a P-channel MOSFET gate means that the motor will turn **on** if the input is open.

Comment: I'm indeed using a pull-up, I'm sorry, I mixed up. Do you think 4K7 is not enough resistance? Also, won't it damage the AVR pin if I leave out the gate resistor?

Comment: It will work fine, but a bit low value, in my opinion. No it won't damage the AVR pin- it will see a brief pulse of current to charge/discharge the gate charge. If you want to use a resistor probably 50-100 ohms would be okay, but better to put it after the pull-down to get more gate voltage (the part you used is 1.8V though so not much worry).